# Can Apache prepend a header file to any request?

Tags: apache, apache-modules

Is it possible to prepend a header file (for example header.php) to any request (for example page.html)    without  URL Rewriting | redirecting URLs with Apache's mod_rewrite | Running as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by setting [`auto_prepend_file` option](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) in the `php.ini` (PHP configuration). This will only work when other PHP files are requested.